# Laravel - Unable to Dump Query Result

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get the result of query just like on this [example](https://laravel-news.com/quickly-dumping-laravel-queries).

I have tried like the example given but I did not get any output. May I know what I am doing wrong?

Below are the example:

**AppServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use DB;
use Event;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        if (env('APP_ENV') === 'local') {
            DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
            Event::listen('kernel.handled', function ($request, $response) {
                if ($request->has('sql-debug')) {
                    $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
                    dd($queries);
                }
            });
        }

        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
}
```

**SeasonRecord.php**

```
public function index()
{
    $cars = User::where('id', 3)
    ->get();

    // return view('seasonRecord', compact('cars'));
}
```

**Web.php**

```
Route::get('/record', 'SeasonRecord@index');
```

On my `.env` file the `APP_ENV` is set to `local`

For the url I wrote `http://127.0.0.1:8000/record?sql-debug=1` but no result is shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No more `kernel.handled` from Laravel version 5.4. [Change set](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/43a5e5f341cc8affd52e77019f50e2d96feb94a5)

Please try below code

```
...
Event::listen(\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Events\RequestHandled::class, function ($event) {                         
    if ($event->request->has('sql-debug')) {    
        $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
        dd($queries);
    }
});
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Need to read a lot on this. Is there a documentation for this?

Comment: @Khairul I usually check Laravel official documentation and ask google / stackoverflow. Also I go through Laravel source code for more investigations.